# ViewPager: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions and Index Out of bound exception

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager within a ViewPager and I am getting this exception

```
09-07 18:30:26.392: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1331)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:422)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:86)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:453)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onAttachedToWindow(ViewPager.java:563)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:7974)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1857)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1862)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1862)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:2968)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:2824)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView(ViewPager.java:537)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:2781)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:2761)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:848)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1041)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:616)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1359)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:422)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:86)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:453)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onAttachedToWindow(ViewPager.java:563)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:7974)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1857)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1862)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1862)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1862)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1862)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:726)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1944)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And also tabs are recreated when every i open the fragment.
And yes I know there are other ways to do this but I want the snappness and the scrolling for free. Also I would like to understand how it actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Handler.post() to set adapter outside of original fragment transaction:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);     
    }
});  }
```